# How to display the sound amplitude in an android app live without saving it.I have already tried the following code

Tags: android

These are the two activities.In the main acitivity i have created an object    for Class Soundmeter and used it to retrieve the max amplitude value from Soundmeter class.I have assigned the retrieved value into a textbox.

Main Activity class:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SoundMeter mSensor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    final TextView t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pt);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                mSensor.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //  t1.setText((int) mSensor.getAmplitude());
            //   t1.setText("Hello");
        }
    });

    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {
            mSensor.stop();
            t1.setText((int) mSensor.getAmplitude());
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

SoundMeter Activity,that i have copied from project on google code,but it         doesnt seem to work .I dont know why , is there a problem in calling a method of this class from main activity ?

```
import android.media.MediaRecorder;

import java.io.IOException;

public class SoundMeter {
static final private double EMA_FILTER = 0.6;

private MediaRecorder mRecorder = null;
private double mEMA = 0.0;

public void start() throws IOException {
    if (mRecorder == null) {
        mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
        mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mRecorder.setOutputFile("/dev/null");
        mRecorder.prepare();
        mRecorder.start();
        mEMA = 0.0;
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (mRecorder != null) {
        mRecorder.stop();
        mRecorder.release();
        mRecorder = null;
    }
}

public double getAmplitude() {
    if (mRecorder != null)
        return  (mRecorder.getMaxAmplitude()/2700.0);
    else
        return 0;

}

public double getAmplitudeEMA() {
    double amp = getAmplitude();
    mEMA = EMA_FILTER * amp + (1.0 - EMA_FILTER) * mEMA;
    return mEMA;
}
}
```

Comment: you need a timer which update amplitude interval, like 200ms.

Comment: Thanks , but can u be more more specific , i am a beginner here .
how can i implement a timer in this and where should i add it ?